# Hash and encryption in combination: Preserve security

Tags: security, encryption, hash

I would like to protect my database of secret information with a master key or master password and encrypt the data. Only if the user enters the correct master key, the data will be decrypted.

Obviously, when creating the master key, I should only save this as a hash value (e.g. SHA). But then I also need a key to encrypt the data with (e.g. AES). I thought of using the master key's hash value as the key for encryption.

But probably, this is not safe, right?

If the user enters a key, the hash is calculated and compared to the saved hash value. If they are the same, the database should be enrypted.

But saving the master key's hash value and using it as the key for encryption is probably a security risk, right?

Should I rather use the actual (plaintext) version of the master key to encrypt the data with?

Or just leaving out the step with comparing the hash value to the entered password and instead just trying to encrypt the data with the password entered?

I hope you understand what I'm trying to tell you about my problem. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just protect the database access with a password?Why do you also want to encrypt the data?

Comment: Maybe to protect against attacks like SQL injection or any other which gain access to the data in the database only?

Comment: @Hanno:Protect from an SQL injection by encypting the data?Seems too much to me.Let alone that if an SQL injection is possible the data can be corrupted and encryption does not help there

Comment: Yep, SQL injections and the like can break a lot of things in a DB. - Or, let's say, one of last month's backup tapes of your database takes some weird detour via untrusted hands... Software access protection does not help here anymore.

Comment: Oh , but: For passwords, encryption really only is the 2nd best approach. If you *can* do with salted&hashed passwords, *do* it!

Comment: I want to protect the database access with a password, yes. But this is not enough. How can you prevent unauthorized users from accessing the database if the database is not encrypted? So it must be encrypted and only decrypted, if access is granted to the user. Right?

Comment: I don't want to store the passwords just to check if someone enters the correct one. They must be recoverable so that I can show them again later. So hashing them is not the approach to choose I think. It must be encryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is always best to separate responsibilities clearly and only use one cryptographic entity for one purpose and nothing else.

For symmetric encryption (e.g. AES), you need a *key*, and such a key is typically derived from a password (but it can be derived from a lot of other things, like a collection of files, or even just entered directly). So this entity is "password-which-becomes-encryption-key". Use it for that purpose. No need to store the password anywhere, as deriving the correct key from it is all you need.

If you additionally want to guard access to your application or database with an account system with authentication and authorisation, you also need to manage those credentials. That's an entirely unrelated activity; look up any basic web application design guide for standard solutions.

Just don't reuse a login password as an encryption key.

Comment: Thanks, you've understood my problem correctly :) Imagine we have a password database (like "PasswordSafe"). The user enters passwords which are stored in the database. To prevent unauthorized users from accessing the data, we encrypt the file (e.g. AES) using the "master key" the user entered. Right? But if the user wants sto see the list again later, we must check if he enters the correct password, right? And so I should save a hash of the "master key" in order to check if it is correct and then, if yes, decrypt the data with the entered password. Do you understand?

Comment: I don't think you need any extra "checking". You can just preface your list with a recognizable identifier (like `"Works!"`), and when the user enters the password (or any other suitable key derivator), you just check if the first six bytes decrypt to the magic string. I don't see an independent authentication scheme in your design, nor would one add any genuine security. (What I described is essentially how TrueCrypt does it -- you can tell from the key material whether you got the right key, simple as that.)

Comment: TrueCrypt is a great example! If I take a look at security tools such as TrueCrypt, they always feature two different kinds of algorithms: You have to choose one algorithm which does the encryption and decryption (e.g. AES) and, besides, another algorithm which is used to generate the hash values (e.g. SHA). It is like that, right? So TrueCrypt saves the hash value of the entered master key - or what is the hash for?

Comment: Hashing is typically used for key generation: The symmetric cipher requires a key, and the user enters a password; so a hash function is applied to the password (and related material) to create the key. Basically what I already said above.

Comment: Thanks! And why not just use the entered password as the key? Because it is too short? Thus apply a hashing algorithm?

Comment: @MarcoW.: Indeed, the key needs to be of a fixed length; the password doesn't. Also, more practically, a typed password will only cover a very small range of possible byte values, which would be a dramatic weakening of the search space of possible keys!

Comment: Why must the key be of a fixed length? Sorry for that stupid question. I've never read that before. I can encrypt data with AES even with a 5-character-key, can't I? And, of course, the key seems to be stronger if it is a hash. But if you know which hash algorithm is used, there isn't any advantage in security, is it? You just try your brute force passwords as usual but calculate the hash before you try them.

Comment: @MarcoW.: That's just how the cipher works. You can read up the details of the algorithm if you're interested.