# Encrypting with one hash and storing another

Tags: function, security, encryption, hash, aes

I want to implement a system where by encrypted data can be stored alongside everything you need to decrypt it except a human memorable password. The system I have in mind is that the encrypted data would be stored with the key that was used to encrypt that data, only that key would have been encrypted again using the hash of the users password. There would then be another hash of the password also stored in the same place, but this hash would have used a different hash function.

The decryption process would be:

1. user enters password
2. the password is hashed using hash function A and that hash is checked against the stored hash to ensure it was correct
3. if the password was correct, you rehash the given password with hash function B to get Key 1
4. Key 1 can then be used to decrypt Key 2 which was used to encrypt a block of data

This way you could store unlimited encrypted data, all encrypted using different randomly generated AES keys that are all encrypted by the hash of the password (Key 1). Ideally you could give this block of data to anyone and they couldn't decrypt it without the password. You could also send the password hash and a single block of encrypted data over a network and the end user can decrypt it on their end assuming they know the password.

I know the standard response to these things is don't roll your own, but I would like to know out of interest what the security concerns are for this system. Primarily Could it work and what pair of hash functions should be used and why? I am also interested in what the standard way to achieve this would be.

Comment: You dont need a full verification hash, you can just attempt the decryt and fail if it does not athenticate (you do need to use authenticated encryption). You should also use a approvd password strengthening KDF like PBKDF2. I would also add a salt (stored with the data).

Comment: BTW: symmetric password based PGP encryption does exactly that (with outdated crypto).

Comment: Ah ok .. Thank you eckes I will look into authenticated encryption. Also I realised that this is probably a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940348/hash-and-encryption-in-combination-preserve-security?rq=1